# Horizontal Centered Menu in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to make a horizontal centered menu. I have tried using things like text align center and margin auto but can't get them to work. I do not want to use a table.

Here's my code:

```
<footer class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <ul>
                <li>footer info 1</li>
                <li>footer info 2</li>
                <li>footer info 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please post your CSS.

Comment: how do you want your links, inline or one below the other

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the provided HTML:

```
ul { text-align: center; }
li { display: inline-block; } /* Don't float them */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NpLR3/

Answer (score 1):

The following will work **without using `text-align`**:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
.span12 {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

The important bits are:

(1) that the outer container for the menu has 100% width,

(2) that the inner container is absolutely positioned at 50% left (which positions the left side of the menu at the center of the page), and

(3) that the menu is then relatively positioned at -50% left (moving it back to the left half its width, so that the center of the menu is now at the center of the page).

The other stuff is just cosmetic.

[See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/QkzzC/).

Comment: The OP never says that they want to avoid using text-align, only that they couldn't figure out how to make it work.  This is a very roundabout doing it.

Comment: @cimmanon, agreed. I'm just providing another option.  There is more than one way to skin a cat.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yzh76/)

```
.container{
    background:#ddd;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/aCSgz/

Basically you need to set the ul and li to display: block.

```
ul { display: block; text-align:center; }
ul li { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `display` property on the LIs to `inline-block` and set the `text-align` on the UL to `center`.

HTML:

```
<footer class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <ul>
                <li>footer info 1</li>
                <li>footer info 2</li>
                <li>footer info 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    background:#fdd;
}
div.row {
    background: #dfd;
}
ul {
    background: #ddf;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/h2gT3/1/