# How to fix reversed header?

Tags: html, css

I know that when you put `float: right` to a `li` element it displays in a reversed order, but how can I fix the order so it displays "correctly" and on the right side of the website? Now it displays in the `left` side of the website. I've tried to read some old questions but didn't find anything that could help me, and also, how can I make the `header` display in the middle of the `#333333` colored header without padding? Will `auto` element work?

```css
.header {
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.upper_header ul {
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}
.upper_header li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: left;
}
.upper_header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="headerContainer">
    <ul class="upper_header">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried putting `float: right` to the `ul` element and `float: left` to the `li` element, then the order is correct but the `position` of it is in the `left`. (Sorry for putting two questions in one thread, didn't want to wait another 30 minutes to submit another question.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal Centered Menu in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197216/horizontal-centered-menu-in-css)

Comment: That could work, but can I position the header on the right side as the header is in the middle of everything? @Areim

Comment: Pretty much every approach has been covered in [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224476/span-float-reverse-order). The most common approach has been given by Martin below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your LI's to `display: inline-block` then you dont need to use floats.
Inline-block elements then can be aligned using text-align

Note:
Inline-block can cause a space between elements, for more info about then please read this https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

```css
.header {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
.upper_header {
  width: 100%;
}
.upper_header li {
  display: inline-block
}
.upper_header a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="headerContainer">
    <ul class="upper_header">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be wary that `display: inline-block;` will sometimes create extra space between elements so if you need them "touching", inline-block can sometimes be troublesome.

Comment: There is a mistake in code, class `.upper_header ul` does not have effect, because `ul` is not nested under `upper_header` - just for your info

Comment: Thanks for the comments above, i have updated the answer to reflect these.

Answer (score 2):

First - you have some mistakes in your code, in CSS you use `.upper_header ul`, but this is not correct syntax in your context. Right is `ul.upper_header` (your `ul` list is not under class `upper_header`, but on the same level), so it does not have effect for you.

If you don't need so much nested `div` and not so much classes, prevent using it. Example is below (this is solution with centered menu):

```
.header ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
.header li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqhesrjn/4/

Then you can easily play with `text-align: right` in `ul` element

```
.header ul {
    text-align: right;
    list-style: none;
}
.header li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqhesrjn/3/

Comment: Thanks for letting me learn something new today, really appreciate it. @Areim

Answer (score 0):

slightly modified CSS & you are using wrong selector(.upper_header ul)instead of ul.upper_header.

`ul.upper_header ==> center to align center
ul.upper_header ==> right to align right`

```css
.header {
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.upper_header {
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.upper_header li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.upper_header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="headerContainer">
    <ul class="upper_header">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as well ,one of the many options available depending upon ofcourse what you are trying to get as an end result.and you were using that upper_header class in a wrong way,you dont even need that.

```
.header {
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.headerContainer{width:30%;
float:right;}

.headerContainer ul li {
 display:inline;
}

.headerContainer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```